# Solve ODE initial value problem: $\dot{u}=(2t+u-3)^2-2 , u(1)=0$ Separation of variables fails

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this ODE initial value problem

$\dot{u}=(2t+u-3)^2-2 \hspace{2cm}u(1)=0$

So I tried seperating the variables somehow but to no avail. How else could I tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the variables: $v = u + 2t-3$ then the equation gets to

$\dot{v} = v^2 $ Which is separable. The solutions are $v = \frac{1}{c-t}$ and $v=0$

So $u = 3 - 2t$ and $u = 3 - 2t +  \frac{1}{c-t}$.

If $u(1) = 0$ then $-1 = \frac{1}{c-1} $ Hence $c = 0$

Comment: For a polished answer, I would add that this manipulation yields a well known Riccati form !

Comment: @Rebellos Could you elaborate this? Is it right that this case is special. but arbitrary Riccati equation leads to second-order ODE?

Comment: The initial equation indeed fullfills the initial derived form for the Riccati derivation.